# how do I insert a range of data in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am running this right now:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());
for ($i = 0; $i <= 20; $i++) {
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_table(user_id) values('$i')");
}
```

The problem is, it creates rows from 1-20. I need rows from 1500-1999 though. How would I do that?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `0` and `20` in your `for` loop? What happened?

Comment: You need to [stop using mysql_ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: It's hard to believe that the coincidental `<= 20` (less or equal 20) in the code never struck you.

Comment: What do you mean be needing rows 1500 to 1999? If you want entries in my_table with user_id equal to those values, just change your for loop start & end values. Also note @Machavity's comment.

Comment: change the $i Values to $i=1500; $i<2000;$i++

Answer (score -1):

first of all use run the following query on your table

ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1500;

and after that use your code

```
$conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());
for ($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++) {
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_table(user_id) values('$i')");
}
```

As you already know mysql_query() is depreciation function for new PHP version
you might want to use mysqli instead.

Answer (score -3):

First off, don't use mysql_* functions, as Machavity has pointed out. Use mysqli_* functions.

As others have said in the comments, try changing the $i values for initial and boundary checks.